# Android javax.io.IOException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, ioexception, fileinputstream

I am trying to make a encryption and decryption app but in decryption method I got javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

```
byte[] key = ("Sh").getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
key = sha.digest(key);
key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

public void dec (String dir)
{       
    try{            
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);            
        String cleartextFile = dir;         
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);                   
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);

        block = new byte[6];
        while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
            fos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
        fos.close();        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Chiper Error"+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an SHA-1 digest of the key?

Comment: What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: i am using SHA-1 digest  to make the key static , and the full stacktrace is 04-17 23:48:36.288: W/System.err(1923): java.io.IOException: last block incomplete in decryption

Comment: So the last block of the encrypted file is incomplete. How did you encrypt it?